# Py2app build runs perfectly when run from command line or the executable in the pkg, but not when the app is double clicked

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I have a program that I'm trying to distribute with py2app. When I run the program from the command line, it works without any problems. It also works if I go into the package that py2app creates and find the exec inside the package contents and run it from there. There are not any errors in the output during the build process.

However, when I double click the app in the dist folder, I get an error that says MyApplication Error and has a button to terminate and one to go to the Mac Python website.

I'm using py2app with Python2.7 on Snow Leopard. I'm not using the system Python, this is a distribution I installed myself.

How can I trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the Console (Applications > Utilities). All stack traces from py2app applications get printed there.

I had this problem today, and my solution was that there was something broken with argv_emulation in py2app itself, so I had to set it to False in the OPTIONS dict. It's set to True by default.